# Different work of the script in Windows and in FreeBSD

Tags: python, cookies, suds

I'm writing some script, that works with web-servers.

So, I have the following code:

```
client = suds.client.Client(WSDLfile)
client.service.Login('mylogin', 'mypass')
print client.options.transport.cookiejar
#######
sessnum = str(client.options.transport.cookiejar).split(' ')[1]
client = suds.client.Client( WSDLfile, headers= { 'Set-Cookie' : sessnum } )
```

When running in FreeBSD, it returns

```
<cookielib.CookieJar[<Cookie sessnum=9WAXQ25D37XY535F6SZ3GXKSCTZG8CVJ for .IP.IP.IP.IP/>]>
```

but in Windows it returns

```
<cookielib.CookieJar[]>
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: What does the actual response you get back on the Windows side say? Also, take a look at the requests you are sending out on both platforms to see if they differ any: import logging; logging.getLogger('suds.client').setLevel(logging.DEBUG); logging.getLogger('suds.transport').setLevel(logging.DEBUG).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK client.options.transport.cookiejar is an iterable so what happens on each system when you have:

```
for c in client.options.transport.cookiejar:
    print client.options.transport.cookiejar
```

Failing that, what if in your Windows system you don't have cookies allowed? That may stop the  session from being saved.